# How to change styles of react component using styled components

Tags: styled-components

I have this React component which is a simple button component:

```
const Button = ({ children }) => <button>{children}</button>;
```

I tried to pass the above component inside a `styled` in order to try to change its styles like this:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  color: yellow; //does not work

  button {
    color: yellowgreen; //does not work
  }
`;
```

I am new to  styled components so I am not even sure this is possible to do.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using styled-components for your custom React components, styled-components needs to know where to inject the CSS you want to give to your `<button>` tag. This is done by passing the `className` prop to your `Button` component and passing it as a prop to the `<button>` tag.

Please try to edit your code like so:

```
const Button = ({ children, className }) => <button className={className}>{children}</button>;
```

You can read more about it here [Styled Components - Existing CSS](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css).